# VirtualBox VM Netflix is choppy on chrome

Tags: virtualbox, google-chrome, netflix

In Ubuntu 15.10 inside virtual box in Chrome my Netflix is choppy. I have updated everything. Any ideas.

Comment: Did you install guest additions and enable 3D acceleration? Working in a VM is not going to be as smooth as a native system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04: very slow UI in Oracle VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453106/ubuntu-14-04-very-slow-ui-in-oracle-virtualbox)

Comment: Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox